# Can be URLs of Ajax request be made without hashes?

Tags: ajax, url, mod-rewrite

I've configured mod_rewrite on the site, and all URLs look like `site.com/smth/else`

In profile section of the site I want to make ajax navigation, so URLs will be changed with hashes: `site.com/profile#smth`

Can I make these ajax URLs look like others (with slashes but not hashes) - is it possible?

Comment: What's your main issue? bookmarking, just visual consistency, or something else? What's your goal?

Comment: goal is to keep urls `site.com/smth/else/` on every page of the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. The only possible way to change current url without reloading of the whole page - is to change its anchor part.

Comment: To clarify: hashes make reload-free navigation possible on *clientside*, which has nothing to do with mod_rewrite.